# Find the residue of $1!+2!+........+n! \pmod{m}$ for $m>n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

> Find the residue of $ 1!+2!+........+n! \pmod{m}$ for $m>n$

$n,m$ are positive numbers and need not be primes.

is there any known proof or result for this thanks

Answer (score 1):

At least we can say that this is equivalent to $1! + 2! + \cdots + (m-1)! \pmod{m}$

Comment: sorry i made a mistake i changed my question please check thanks